# How to group by and select max date?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE usages (
usage number not null,
date_recorded date not null,
category varchar2(100) not null
name varchar2(100) not null
);
```

| usage | date_recored | category | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2021-01-01 | Red | Bob |
| 15 | 2021-01-02 | Red | Bob |
| 8 | 2021-01-03 | Red | Bob |
| 24 | 2021-01-02 | Blue | Bob |

I want to group by the category and delete the row with the maximum date recorded. So my result would look like

| usage | date_recored | category | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 2021-01-03 | Red | Bob |
| 24 | 2021-01-02 | Blue | Bob |

However, my result ends up essentially showing everything.

```
SELECT
usage, max(date_recorded), category, name
from usages
group by name, category, usages
```

When I do this:

```
SELECT
max(usage), max(date_recorded), category, name
from usages
group by name, category
```

It then shows me the result I want, expect the usage is 15, rather than 8.

| usage | date_recored | category | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 2021-01-03 | Red | Bob |
| 24 | 2021-01-02 | Blue | Bob |